# Swapping two elements' position logic behind

Tags: dart

I came across using *insert* and *removeAt* methods to make 2 elements swap their position in a list, like in the following code example:

```
var list = [1, 2];
list.insert(1, list.removeAt(0));
```

I did my best to grasp the logic behind, but I can't no matter what.
there is insert at **position 1** and then remove at **position 2**. Is that mean that we insert in P1 what we remove from P2?

Could you explain how it works. Thanks

Comment: This is a bad way to swap elements in a `List`.  It turns what should be a trivial O(1) operation into an O(n) operation.“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.removeAt(int index1)` removes the value at  and returns the value at given index1.
Similarly `list.insert(int index2, E element)` inserts element E at given index2.

So what's happening is, when you call

```
var list = [1, 2];
list.insert(1, list.removeAt(0));
```

list.removeAt(0) removes the element at index 0 first and then returns 1(the element at position 0) then the list looks like `[2]` and the statement looks like `list.insert(1,1);` and , with element 2 at index 0, now the statement means to insert element 1 at index 1 so the list will be updated to `[2,1]` which is equivalent to swapping.

This works only because the element at position 0 is 1 what if there is some other element at position 0 then the insertion would result in undesired output.
Hope you get my point.

Comment: For more about insert and removeAt follow this [insert](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-list-insert-method-in-dart)  and [removeAt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/List/removeAt.html#:~:text=Removes%20the%20object%20at%20position,Returns%20the%20removed%20object.)